# Does "init" run in kernel space?

Tags: kernel

I am new to linux,just want to ask which processes run in kernel space? I read somewhere that init runs in user space.But init boots up the system,it should run in kernel space.

Please clarify my doubt.Thanks in advance.

Bruce

Comment: The kernel runs in kernel space. 'Init' is not the kernel. 'Init' *interacts* with the kernel and supervises the other processes..

Comment: "But init boots up the system,it should run in kernel space." why does the first mean the second should be true?